# GTK3 resize attempt grows window exponentially

Tags: c, image, resize, gtk3

I have a C GTK3 program that has a notebook with two images. I want to be able to grab the corner of the window and adjust the size of the image currently displayed. What I currently have is a program that once started, the window keeps growing until I kill it from the terminal using ctrl-c. I put a sleep call in the callback to slow it down, but it still grows. How do I stop the window from growing unless I "grab" a corner of the window and adjust it myself?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>

GtkWidget *notebook;

gboolean resize_image(GtkWidget *widget, GdkRectangle *allocation,
    gpointer user_data)
{
    int w,h, pagenum;
    GdkPixbuf *pxbscaled;
    GtkWidget *image;
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;

    pagenum = gtk_notebook_get_current_page (GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook));
    image = gtk_notebook_get_nth_page (GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), pagenum);
//  GtkImageType image_type = gtk_image_get_storage_type
//      (GTK_IMAGE(image));

    pixbuf = gtk_image_get_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(image));

    h = allocation->height;
    w = (gdk_pixbuf_get_width(pixbuf) * h) / gdk_pixbuf_get_height(pixbuf);

    pxbscaled = gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple(pixbuf, w, h, GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR);

    printf("Allocation height %d width %d.\n", h, w);

    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(image), pxbscaled);

    g_object_unref (pxbscaled);

    sleep(2);

    return FALSE;
}

static gboolean delete( GtkWidget *widget,
            GtkWidget *event,
            gpointer   data )
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
    return FALSE;
}

int main( int argc,
      char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *table;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *image;
    int i;
    char bufferl[32];

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
//  gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET(window), 800, 480);

    g_signal_connect (window, "delete-event",
              G_CALLBACK (delete), NULL);

    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

    table = gtk_grid_new ();
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);

    /* Create notebook, place position of tabs */
    notebook = gtk_notebook_new ();
    gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos (GTK_NOTEBOOK (notebook), GTK_POS_TOP);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (table), notebook, 0, 6, 3, 3);
    gtk_widget_show (notebook);

    /* Append pages to the notebook */
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sprintf(bufferl, "Page %d", i + 1);

        if (i == 0) {
            image = gtk_image_new_from_file("image1.jpg");
        } else {
            image = gtk_image_new_from_file("image2.jpg");
        }

        gtk_widget_set_halign(image, GTK_ALIGN_START);
        gtk_widget_set_valign(image, GTK_ALIGN_START);

        g_signal_connect(window, "size-allocate", 
            G_CALLBACK(resize_image), NULL);

        label = gtk_label_new (bufferl);
        gtk_notebook_append_page (GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), 
            image, label);
    }

    /* Create a close button */
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("close");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked",
                  G_CALLBACK (delete), NULL);

    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (table), button, 0, 10, 1, 1);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

A user will need to provide image1.jpg and image2.jpg. Edit out the sleep call will result in the program filling the screen extremely quickly.

EDIT: I have also asked this question on the gtk mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window with the image was growing because I was applying the size of the ***window*** to the image. Hence the image got larger and thus made the window get larger. Which continued in an endless progression, the "size-allocate" signal was constantly being called.
I fixed it by limiting the allocation height in the call back, by multiplying it by 0.75. 
Now I can expand and contract the window with ease and it does not grow out of control.
The image does get ugly quite quickly, but that is another problem.